# How to implement a repository when I use different algorithms for analysing data, but the same algorithm for extracting it?

Tags: android, repository, mvp, separation-of-concerns

I'm trying to create an app which uses Jsoup to extract data from different web pages, analyse it and get the products.

There are 3 different web pages and each page analyser class implements Analyser interface

```
public interface Analyser {

    void setDocument(Document document);
    ArrayList<Item> analyseDocument(String searchFor);
}

public class WebPageNumberOne implements Analyser {

    @Override
    void setDocument(Document document){
        //sets document for analysing
    }

    public ArrayList analyseDocument(String searchFor) {
        //returns data from web page number one
    }

}

public class WebPageNumberTwo implements Analyser {

    @Override
    void setDocument(Document document){
        //sets document for analysing
    }

    @Override
    public ArrayList analyseDocument(String searchFor) {
        //returns data from web page number two
    }

}

public class WebPageNumberThree implements Analyser {

    @Override
    void setDocument(Document document){
        //sets document for analysing
    }

    @Override
    public ArrayList analyseDocument(String searchFor) {
        //returns data from web page number three
    }
}
```

I also have a repository which takes Analyser, gets a document using Jsoup and passes it to the Analyser

```
public class DocumentItemsRepository implements ItemsRepository {

    private String searchFor;
    private String URL;
    private Document document;
    private Analyser analyser;
    private MainActivityPresenter presenter;

    public void setSearchFor(String searchFor) {
        this.searchFor = searchFor;
    }

    public void setURL(String URL) {
        this.URL = URL;
    }

    public void setAnalyser(Analyser analyser) {
        this.analyser = analyser;
    }

    public void setPresenter(MainActivityPresenter presenter){
        this.presenter = presenter;
    }

    @Override
    public ArrayList<Item> getItems() {
    }

    private class GetDocumentAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Document> 
    {
    }
}
```

In my presenter, I have a method `loadItems` which takes Repository implementation and sets its dependencies via setter injection and gets the items.

I did this because sometimes I want to pass different analysers to the repository, but the web page content extraction is the same.

```
public class MainActivityPresenter {

    private MainActivityView mainActivityView;

    public MainActivityPresenter(MainActivityView mainActivityView) {
        this.mainActivityView = mainActivityView;
    }

    public void loadItems(String URL, String searchFor, Analyser analyser, 
    DocumentItemsRepository documentItemsRepository)
    {
        documentItemsRepository.setAnalyser(analyser);
        documentItemsRepository.setSearchFor(searchFor);
        documentItemsRepository.setURL(URL);
        documentItemsRepository.setPresenter(this);
        documentItemsRepository.getItems();
    }

}
```

The problem is that I can't test my `loadItems` method because I use setter injection to inject the repository and I pass the implementation and not the interface.

How can I refactor my code so it can be testable and become cleaner?

Should I set analysers using constructor injection, initialise different repositories, pass them when creating the presenter and create individual `loadItems` for each of the repositories with different analyser

```
presenter = new MainActivityPresenter(this, new DocumentItemsRepository1(new Analyser1()), new DocumentItemsRepository2(new Analyser2()));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to initialize the presenter without giving it a dependency to repositories.

```
presenter = new MainActivityPresenter(this);
```

And when trying to load the items from different web pages using different analysers, I pass the initialization of the repository to the **loadItems** method.

```
presenter.loadItems(new DocumentItemsRepository(new FirstAnalyser(), FirstURL, searchFor ));

presenter.loadItems(new DocumentItemsRepository(new SecondAnalyser(), SecondURL, searchFor ));
```

This way the **loadItems** method is still testable and I can mock the repository without provinding the implementation.